# Image with transparent background movement (Visual Studio 2013, C#)

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio, transparent

I am making a windows form application in C# and i'm having some problems with the movement of images with transparency. I have 4 pictureboxes with .png images with transparent background (changing the BackColor and parent properties) and I use the following code to move them:

```
 public class runner {
   public PictureBox PictBox = null;
   public int Pos = 0;
   public int MaxLenght = 800;
...

 public bool Run()
        {

            int distance = Rand.Next(1, 5);

            PictBox.Location = new Point(PictBox.Location.X + distance, PictBox.Location.Y);
            Pos += distance;
            if (Pos >= MaxLenght) return true;
            else return false;
        } 
}
```

...

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        runners = new Runner[]{new Runner(pictureBox3), new Runner(pictureBox4), new Runner(pictureBox5), new Runner(pictureBox6)};
```

...

```
        int n = 0;
        while (!victory){
          foreach(Runner runn in runners)
            {
                n +=1;
                if (runn.Run())
                {
                    victory = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is that if the images have transparent backcolor only the first and the last "frames" are showed (the image in the first position and the image in the last position once the while ends). If you know how to solve the problem please help me D:
Thanks in advance.

PD: The problem appears when I change the BackColor property to transparent, the parent property doesn't affect.

Comment: So basically you are moving 4 picboxes. Try with only one and see what happens.

Comment: Don't use loops in GUI code.  Google "C# game loop" to get ahead.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I've tried with only one image and still not working. In the other hand it's not exactly a game and I have to make it using that loop (my teacher wants so).

Comment: Try using a timer instead.

Comment: Thanks but as I've said, I can't use a timer, it has to be made with that loop.